# Which is correct: "anytime" or "any time"?

Tags: word-usage

Is it "any time" or "anytime" or are those two things different?

Comment: Can you give a context where you've seen those two? Otherwise, what did a dictionary say? or google for them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One may write

> Call me anytime
>
> Call me any time
>
> Call me at any time

but not

> *Call me at anytime

because *anytime* is used as an adverb and not a noun.

Comment: +1. It's still not clear. What is anytime anyway? preposition? Adjective adverb? pronoun? What?

Comment: Why not? and Why so?

Comment: @Jim: have you checked a dictionary? What did it say?

Comment: So anytime is an adverb and "any time" is an adverb phrase. Am I correct here? They are used interchangeably. Why call me at anytime is wrong?

Comment: @JimThio In “Call me any time”, your *any time* is an NP being used adverbially. You know it is an NP because *any* is a determiner.

Comment: NP is noun phrase?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the explanation:  "At" is a preposition, so it must be followed by a noun.  The noun in the example is "time."  "Any" is an adjective modifying the noun "time."  It's like "Call me at four o'clock.  Call me at night. Call me at any hour of the day or night." 
But "anytime" is an adverb, like "anyhow" or "anyway."  It's like "Call me early" or "Call me occasionally." 
So why did the answer indicate that "Call me any time" is also acceptable?  Because using "anytime" is more informal.  The word does not even appear in the Webster's New World Dictionary of 1988.  However, it does appear in the online dictionary (dictionary.reference.com).  Evidently, the use of "anytime" has become more acceptable.

Comment: Call me at once?